# Find beta-testers for opendata site

Tags: web-application

I've launched the community-driven opendata non-profitable site, and want to find the beta-tester enthusiasts. Can you suggest where I can to contact them?

Answer (score 1):

My only suggestion would be to get involved with forum(s) that coincide with your non-profits objective(s).  Your first post should have nothing to do with your own site.  Change your signature to an image that links to your site.  Get involved with said forum(s) and more importantly, find out if most members truly do line up with your objective(s).

Once you gain some reputation, post counts, etc. it is time to ask if anyone is interested in getting involved.  Go from there...

Comment: I think, this is a way to attract the new interested visitors, in my area this a industrial engineers. Is where are a forums of profi testers? May be, here, on SQA?